# Groupby one column and split the count based on another column

Tags: pandas, group-by, pivot

I have a dataframe like so:

```
ID    Category
1        A
1        B
1        A
1        B
2        A
2        C
2        C
2        A
2        D
3        E
```

How can I groupby the `ID` column and perform a count of each category?

I.E.

```
ID    A   B   C   D  E
1     2   2   0   0  0
2     2   0   2   1  0
3     0   0   0   0  1
```

I have tried `df.groupby('ID').count()` & `df.groupby('ID')['Category']`

Comment: `pd.crosstab(df.ID,df.Category,df.Category,aggfunc='count').fillna(0)`

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with either `groupby`:

```
df.groupby('ID')['Category'].value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

or `crosstab` (shorter code but a bit slower)

```
pd.crosstab(df.ID, df.Category)
```

Output:

```
Category  A  B  C  D  E
ID                     
1         2  2  0  0  0
2         2  0  2  1  0
3         0  0  0  0  1
```